# Условие на время нажатия клавиш С++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Нужно что бы при нажатии клавиши n-количество раз(допустим 3) за n-количество времени(допустим 2 секунды). И что бы тогда выполнялся мой код. В ином случае, допустим если нажата клавиша
3 раза больше чем за 2 секунды то ничего б не происходило. Перехват клавиш будет глобальный а не консольный. Подскажите что делать или хотя бы куда капать а то вообще без понятия как это реализовать.

Comment: Отлавливаете первое нажатие, запускаете таймер. Пока работает таймер - считаете нажатия. Насчитали, сколько надо - запускаете целевой код. Если таймер досчитал, а нажатий не набралось - сбрасываете счетчик нажатий, и возвращаетесь к начальному состоянию

Comment: хорошая идея, спасибо